# Meteor recursive method call causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, meteor

Given a (parent) node in a tree, i need to retrieve [1] Number of children under parent plus under the parent's children plus parent's children's children and so on [2] Number of children from [1] that are marked "OPEN".

My test data has one parent which has two children. My method -

```
Meteor.methods({
...
   'getSubCounts': function(selectedNodeId){
    var children = ItemList.find({"parent.parentid": selectedNodeId}).fetch();
    var numChildren = children.length;
    console.log("Number of children of " + selectedNodeId + ": " + numChildren);

    var openChildrenCount = children.filter(function(row) {
        return (row.status === "OPEN");
    }).length;

    for (i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) { 
        console.log("iterations for child " + i + ": " + children[i]._id);

        Meteor.call('getSubCounts', children[i]._id, function(error, result) {
            if(error) {
                console.log("error occured during iteration " + error);
            } else {
                numChildren = numChildren + result.numChildren;
                openChildrenCount = openChildrenCount + result.openChildrenCount;
            }
        });

    }

    return {numChildren: numChildren, openChildrenCount: openChildrenCount};
    },
...
});
```

Which i am invoking in a client-side helper -

```
'subcounts': function(){
    if (this._id != null) {
        Meteor.call('getSubCounts', this._id, function(error, result) {
            if(error) {
                // nothing
            } else {
                Session.set('subcountsdata', result)
            }
        });
```

From the (browser) output, It appears to iterate as expected for the first child but the second one is stuck in an infinite loop. (Note that the parent node id is `8veHSdhXKjyFqYZtx` and the children ids are `iNXvZGaTK3RR6Pekj,C6WGaahHrPiWP7zGe`)

```
Number of children of 8veHSdhXKjyFqYZtx: 2
iterations for child 0: iNXvZGaTK3RR6Pekj
Number of children of iNXvZGaTK3RR6Pekj: 0
iterations for child 1: C6WGaahHrPiWP7zGe 
Number of children of C6WGaahHrPiWP7zGe: 0 
iterations for child 1: C6WGaahHrPiWP7zGe
Number of children of C6WGaahHrPiWP7zGe: 0 
iterations for child 1: C6WGaahHrPiWP7zGe
Number of children of C6WGaahHrPiWP7zGe: 0 
iterations for child 1: C6WGaahHrPiWP7zGe
Number of children of C6WGaahHrPiWP7zGe: 0 
....
```

Why does the second iteration occur infinitely in this case? It looks to be due to the reactivity but i can't quite get to the actual reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very probably you are just missing a `var i` in your method function.

Without declaring `i` as a local variable, you use a global scope variable, which gets re-assigned to 0 everytime you call your method.

BTW:

- avoid recursing Meteor methods. You are creating a loop of network requests. If you need recursing, externalize in a dedicated function.
- avoid calling Meteor methods in helpers. Use `ReactiveVar` instead and make your call only when necessary, typically in a Blaze template lifecycle hook (like onCreated) or in an event listener.

Comment: You're spot on! And thank you those are good points. For now, I have moved the client method call to onCreated() rather than helper.

Comment: Just curious, Is there a potentially better way to get tree data without recursion?

Comment: Probably not in a simple hierarchical tree data structure.